# iis site binding issue. got This site can’t be reached error. how to solve it

Tags: iis

I am new to iis. I have create a website in my iis for my website content. Want to ask how can i bind the domain name with the site in iis for internal use.
this is what i have tried so far.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Run a report and the cause is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to bind the domain name locally you have to bind it in the host file which is located at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.

add your machine IP and domain name as suggested in the below format:

192.168.6.52 domian.com

[image]

by using this method you can only access it on your machine. the host file is only for the machine in which you are accessing the site.

now set the iis site binding as shown below:

[image]

clear browser cache and history and browse your site.

Comment: one more question what if i want to access IIS site from internet?

Comment: @homod if you want to host iis site on the internet then you have to buy the public IP and domain name and bind with the iis site and that's how you can host iis site on internet.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Really appreciate it.